# find the location of the whitish points on an image

Tags: python, pandas, opencv, matplotlib, scipy

```
import matplotlib.image as img
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image1 = img.imread("82.png",0)
image2 = img.imread("83.png",0)

diff = image2 - image1

matchingInd = np.where(diff > 0.6)


diff[matchingInd] = 1
plt.imshow(diff)
```

image1 and image2 has black background with some bright(whitish) points. image2 is the same photo as image1 but just added some bright(whitish) points or deleted some of the bright(whitish) points. How can I find the location of the added bright points on the image2?

Comment: `matchingInd` is not what you are looking for already? Can you elaborate what you mean by find the location, are you looking for the coordinates?

Comment: yes the coordinates

Comment: @user19593840 Please show sample images

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tagged `OpenCV` I have replicated your problem the following way.

Consider 2 image arrays `a` and `b`, where `255` refers to the bright spots:

```
>>> a
array([[  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0, 255,   0, 255,   0,   0, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0, 255, 255,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0, 255,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255,   0, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]],
  dtype=uint8)
```

In `b`, some spots have been **removed** compared to `a` and new spots have been **added**:

```
>>> b
array([[  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255],
       [255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255],
       [255,   0, 255,   0, 255,   0,   0, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0, 255,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0, 255,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]],
  dtype=uint8)
```

Finding **only** the newly added spots in `b` using `cv2.subtract`. This should be read as *elements in `a` are subtracted from elements in `a`*:

```
>>>diff = cv2.subtract(b, a)
```

`diff` contains only the newly added spots:

```
>>> diff
array([[  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255],
       [255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255],
       [255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]],
  dtype=uint8)
```

Now find the coordinates as mentioned above using `np.argwhere`:

```
>>> np.argwhere(diff == 255)
array([[ 0, 11],
       [ 0, 12],
       [ 1,  0],
       [ 1, 12],
       [ 2,  0],
       [ 4, 10],
       [ 5, 10],
       [ 6,  5]], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.where` or `numpy.argwhere`

They will give you the same results but the output shape will be different:

`numpy.where` will give you a tuple with two elements: the array of all the `x` coordinates `(x1, x2, ...)` and the array of all the `y` coordinates `(y1, y2, ...)`

`numpy.argwhere` will give you an array of shape (N, 2) with each row correponfing to the coordinates of one pixel

```
import numpy as np

my_array = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

np.where(my_array < 4)
Out: (array([0, 0, 0]), array([0, 1, 2]))

np.argwhere(my_array < 4)
Out: array([[0, 0],
            [0, 1],
            [0, 2]])
```

Note: using np.argwhere should throw an error when trying to run the following line `diff[matchingInd] = 1`

Comment: Thank you. Subtraction of image2 and image1 doesn't help to find the whitish points added to image2. Do you have any idea to find them?